# How to run azure pack portals on distributed enviroment

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

I installed and configured windows azure pack on 8 virtual machines, 1 component per VM, but after all installed I am trying to run the admin portal or tenant portal and both give me the same error page in IE "this page can't be displayed" when I opened the admin site in firefox from the VM it gave me an error "Unable to connect
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at tnwapserver:30072."

What I feel that there is a missed network configurations I am missing to connect all servers together, but I can't find enough details about this.

So is there any docs describe the network requirements for windows azure pack to make it work? or anyone have experience with configuring azure pack?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the URL to Trusted Sites in IE.

Failing that, open the certificates console for each computer in the environment, export any self-signed certificates from the Personal store, and then import them into the trusted root CA store on the other computers (if you're creating a POC environment - if you're setting up a production environment you should be using certificates from a trusted internal or external CA for ALL the servers, in which case none of this should be necessary).